# Proving that the localised charge distribution potential is indeed a solution to Poisson's equation without Dirac delta function

Tags: electrostatics, potential

I want to prove that the potential of a localised charge distribution:
$$\phi=\iiint_V\frac{\rho(\vec r')d\tau '}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}|\vec r-\vec r'|}$$ is indeed a solution to Poission's equation:
$\nabla^2\phi=-\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}$

Caveat: Without using the Dirac delta function.

If I have to specify a reason, I still don't agree with the process of Dirac delta function, as opposed to many physicists.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't agree with the Green's function technique?

Comment: dear @LienardWiechert, I havent checked out the greens function technique, this is my first read through Griffiths, and it hasnt been introduced. What I am talking about is the verification given in JD Jackson, where he makes use of the dirac delta function to mitigate the issues caused by the laplacian of $\frac{1}{r}$, but I am not able to agree with this as he "assumes" that gauss divergence theorem holds, and then proceeds to conjecture that the laplacian is actually a multiple of the dirac delta function

Comment: I think this may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368155/where-does-the-relation-nabla21-r-4-pi-delta3-bf-r-between-laplacian

Comment: If you dislike the Dirac delta distribution, I think the correct solution is to usher you to study distribution theory. It is mathematically rigorous and sensible; liking it or not does not matter. Yes, we physicists are often sloppy in how we do things, but we are justified once mathematicians prove that our sloppy work actually do work.